# How to place Wordpress files inside laravel project

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess

I have found solutions to put WordPress inside Laravel public folder and then serve it through URLs.

I do not want to do this as it will be very critical to manage my Laravel project through git. Every time WordPress files will be pushed and updated.

I want to manage my Laravel project in different directories and WordPress in a different ones.

The scenario is that I want a WordPress site on my index page. siteexample.com, WordPress blog on siteexample.com/blog, and my Laravel login on siteexample.com/login So maybe it could be done through .htaccess or if there is any other idea or solution please let me know many thanks.

Comment: you can use wordpress rest api for it

Comment: That means I need to develop whole wordpress system myself in laravel.

Comment: yes if you dont want to use wordpress files

Comment: No actually I want to use wordpress files but in different directory from laravel.

Comment: This would be done at the server level, where you would point different URL's to differ root folders. The specifics of how to do this, is dependent on the server you are using.

Comment: I dont want to use different urls. I have a same url pointing to my larave project and now i want to serve wordpress when i open example.com and i want to server laravel when open example.com/login